# The average cost of DPLL (SAT)

Tags: logic, algorithms

What is the average cost of DPLL (Davis–Putnam–Logemann–Loveland) algorithm in SAT problem? The worst case is $O(2^n)$. But what is the average case? Someone could give a specific value? (preferred result of any scientific publication)